# Add only new data to linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

```
if (!head->next) {
    head->next = newNode;   /* if only dummy node, add node to end of list */
} else {
    /* iterates through linked list until a node is found that is greater than the new node */
    while (head->next && strcmpa((head->next)->data, newNode->data) < 0) 
        head = head->next;
    if (!head->next) {
        head->next = newNode;   /* adds new node to end list if no nodes are greater in value */    
    } else {
        newNode->next = head->next;     /* points new node to the next node */  
        head->next = newNode;   /* points current node to new node */
    }
}
```

How can I edit this code to get it to reject any new node whose data field is equal to a node that is already in the list?

Comment: You need to iterate over all the nodes currently present in your linked list and always check if the new node's value is equal to the current node's value. If it is then stop the iteration. If no node in the list holds the same value as the new node, then the loop would end just at the last node in the list, where 'currentNode->next' equals NULL. At this point you need to add the new node by making the last node in the list point to the new node. However, if you want your keep your list sorted, you can then run the piece of code you provided to insert sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the last `else {` into

```
else if(strcmp(head->next->data, newNode->data)) {
```

Comment: You da man. Thanks. Been looking at this code for so long I didn't even know what it meant anymore.

Comment: @namarino Glad to help :D